# Can't figure why I can't read a JSON

Tags: c++, json, qt

I have the following static method which allow me to get an `Airplane` object from a JSON :

```
Airplane AirplaneManager::load(QString airplaneRegistration) {
    QFile loadFile("airplanes/"+airplaneRegistration+".json");
    if (!loadFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        Airplane temp;
        return temp;
    }

    QJsonDocument loadDoc(QJsonDocument::fromJson(loadFile.readAll()));
    QJsonObject airplane = loadDoc.object()["plane"].toObject();

    Airplane temp(airplane["registration"].toString(), airplane["type"].toString()); // creates the airplane object
    // adds some details
    temp.setDateFormat(airplane["dateFormat"].toString());
    temp.setCreatedDate(QDate::fromString(airplane["createdDate"].toString(), temp.getDateFormat()));

    return temp;
}
```

The JSON is this one :

```
{
    "F-FBZH": {
        "createdDate": "29/02/2016",
        "registration": "F-FBZH",
        "type": "DR400-120"
    }
}
```

When I try to access to `airplane["registration"].toString()` it returns an empty QString instead of the airplane registration. Why ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `airplane["F-FBZH"]["registration"]` ?

Comment: actually your registration is inside F-FBZH So  it should be airplane["F-FBZH"]["registration"]

Comment: Does `loadDoc.object()["plane"].toObject();` imply that the word `plane` should appear in the document?

Comment: Clever guys! Thank you!